# SVG image tag zoom in and out animation

Tags: image, animation, svg, zooming

I have my SVG file with various animations written by me, i can't able to zoom image in image tag(I need it as an animation). In SVG circle tag works perfect for zoom in and zoom out animation. please anyone help me by giving your solution in pure SVG.

```
<image id="img_id" x="200" y="200" width="50" height="50" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="my svg image as vector code"/>

<animateTransform
        xlink:href="#img_id"
        begin="1s" values="-150,-150; 0,0" dur="0.5s"
        type="translate"
        attributeName="transform"   
        fill="freeze" additive="sum"/>

    <animateTransform
        xlink:href="#img_id"
        begin="1s" values="2; 1" dur="0.5s"
        type="scale" attributeName="transform" 
        fill="freeze" additive="sum"/>
```

My SVG code in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/c7uymgrn/1/)!

Comment: Perhaps if you added some examples to the question it would be clearer what you're talking about.

Comment: Kindly add some code you have tried. That will help.

Comment: @Robert Longson & @ Jaffer Wilson...  My SVG code in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/c7uymgrn/1/)!

Here one circle tag which works perfect for zoom in and out, but my svg image don't.. Image tag play button didn't zoom in and out like that circle tag. Please help me...

Comment: You have a png image in the jsfiddle, not an SVG image. The image tag does zoom in the fiddle though as it is a raster it is somewhat pixellated. I don't understand what your issue is.

Comment: @Robert Longson... In the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/c7uymgrn/1/)! example the circle tag zoom in and out without translate from one position to another position, but the image tag i have that gets translate when zoom(you can see the difference between the circle and image tag zoom difference). And then, i have converted than play button from png to svg by saving it as .svg using Adobe illustrator and then i used that vector code in my program. If i need original svg image(as like that png play button) how i can get that. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the translate animation for the image till it zooms from its centre. I.e.

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="512" height="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

   <g>
        <circle id="trigger" class="button" cx="150" cy="150" r="25" />
            
        <animateTransform begin="1s" values="-150,-150; 0,0" dur="0.5s"
            type="translate"
            attributeName="transform"   
            fill="freeze"
            additive="sum"/>

        <animateTransform begin="1s" values="2; 1" dur="0.5s"
            type="scale"
            attributeName="transform" 
            fill="freeze" additive="sum"/> 
    </g>
    
   <image id="img_id" x="213" y="233" width="50" height="50" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAZCAYAAAArK+5dAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAK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"/>
   
    <animateTransform
            xlink:href="#img_id"
            begin="1s" values="-238,-258; 0,0" dur="0.5s"
            type="translate"
            attributeName="transform"   
            fill="freeze" additive="sum"/>
    
        <animateTransform
            xlink:href="#img_id"
            begin="1s" values="2; 1" dur="0.5s"
            type="scale" attributeName="transform" 
            fill="freeze" additive="sum"/> 
    
</svg>
```